# Stripe Checkout Script not sending token to server - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup a basic Stripe implementation to use in a project. For whatever reason the stripeToken or any other parameter for that matter is not getting sent to my server, even though the request returns `200 OK`. I have tested using an API client and my server-side code is able to parse body parameters fine.

This is the client-side code. I am using a test api key here.

```
<body>
        <h1>Stripe Test Playground</h1>
        <form action="/charge" method="POST">
          <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="my-api-key-here"
            data-amount="100"
                data-zip-code="false"
            data-name="Fiverr Gig Image Maker"
            data-description="1 image"
            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
            data-locale="auto">
          </script>
        </form>
    </body>
```

The server is using Express. This is only a small portion of the code.

The issue is when I return the request body, it is completely empty.

```
var express = require('express');
var stripe = require('stripe')('my-api-code-here');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

Comment: It kind of looks like a GET request to me than post. I could be wrong.

Comment: `res.send(req.body)` is getting executed before the `console.log(req.body)` call.  Is it possible that NodeJS is just stopping execution of that function before it's logged?  Try reversing those lines.

Comment: @korben Even so, res.send(req.body) is not sending anything because req.body is unpopulated.

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd POST is specified in the server.js file and in the method attribute of the form element. It's not a GET request since I essentially copy/pasted this from Stripe. I've also looked through their documentation and got nothing.

Comment: I would recommend you enter a textfield and a button in the form and cut the script, enter something click submit and see if you get the req.body. if you did. It means the connection is working fine and it's something in the script.